# Wp Google Maps Plugin not working in Safari

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

I'm using WP Google Maps plugin and it's not working (map is showing, but pins aren't dropping) in Safari but seems to be working well in most other browsers.  I researched and found that other people were having similar problems but no real solution seems to have been found.  Does anybody know if there is any fix for this?

Comment: Well, that was easier than expected.  The developers just issued an update to version 6.0.13.  After installing the update, the issue was cleared up.

Comment: Just realized this update DOES NOT fix the issue for the Safari mobil browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update seemed to fix most issues, still a little glitchy though.